# Retrieve data from firebase and filter duplicate fields

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

i want to create a page in my app where i view history of previously entered data from firestore according to date.I have a page where i try to fetch data specific to date entered, but it seems to keep returning duplicate data as shown in the image below[image]

I only want to be able to show a date particular date once in this page but i cant seem to do that. here is the code

```
StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .doc(user?.uid)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                      print(snapshot.data.docs);
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        Get.snackbar(
                          'About Task',
                          'User message',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
                          titleText: const Text(
                            'Failed Adding Task',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                          messageText: const Text(
                            'Something went wrong... Try again',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      if (snapshot.data == null) {
                        const Center(
                          child: Text('Add a task/Transaction'),
                        );
                      }
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final List storeDocs = [];
                        snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                          Map a = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                          storeDocs.add(a);
                          a['id'] = document.id;
                        }).toList();
                        Calculations.getTotalBalance(storeDocs.asMap());
                        return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              TaskModel task =
                                  TaskModel.fromJson(snapshot.data.docs[index]);
                              print(Expenses.multipleDates);
                              return Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    SizedBox(
                                      height: 25,
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Row(
                                          children: [
                                            Container(
                                              width: 53,
                                              height: 80,
                                              child: Text(
                                                task.date,
                                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Text(
                                          task.amount,
                                          style: const TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 15,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                              color: Colors.green),
                                        ),
                                        Column(
                                          children: [
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Text(
                                                  task.amount,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                      fontSize: 15,
                                                      fontWeight:
                                                          FontWeight.w600,
                                                      color: Colors.red),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            SizedBox(
                                              height: 22,
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                GestureDetector(
                                                  onTap: () {
                                                    _showBottomSheet(
                                                        context, task);
                                                  },
                                                  child: GestureDetector(
                                                    onTap: () {
                                                      Navigator.pushNamed(
                                                          context,
                                                          SpreadSheetPage.id,
                                                          arguments: Tasks(
                                                            firestoreDocID:
                                                                task.date,
                                                          ));
                                                    },
                                                    child: Text(
                                                      'View',
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                          color: Colors.blue),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                    const Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.only(left: 65, top: 8),
                                      child: Divider(
                                        thickness: 0.8,
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              );
                            });
                      } else {
                        return Container();
                      }
                    }),
```

here is what my database looks like
[image]

Comment: I don't understand, could you be more explicit about the duplication of the data? On your firestore I can only see one field.

Comment: oh my bad.. By duplicate i mean like for example if i am to add data  lets say on the 14th and then another data on the 14th. On the app where we have date, 14 appears twice. what im looking for is a functionality which kind of queries the database to check if  the value of the field 'date 'entered is the same with another document previously entered before pulling it onto the app.. if it is the same then pull only one date and add to the listview. i hope you understand.

Comment: in the event of two documents having the same date, which element should be shown?

Comment: just pull one of the dates and not the same date appearing twice in listview.. i have been on this issue for a week bro if you can help will be a life saver thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your feedback, here's what I'd do.

Note how you *can't* filter the query for duplicate values *directly* in your query.

There is no way to tell Firestore "get all of the results from this collection, but filter out elements that have a field repeated (or duplicated) in the collection itself". This makes sense since the Firestore SDK performs simple and fast queries through the `where` clause. Read [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) for more info.

This means that the filtering is at your expenses, i.e. you have to implement it yourself and you *will* be charged for all of the reads you do. Note: any workaround to reduce the number of reads (e.g. use the `not-in` clause) is hacky, hard to read and maintain and it just doesn't work for a large dataset (`not-in` would limit your duplicates to 10, in your case), so embrace it.

Considering these premises one could implement the following brute-force solution that reads all the documents from your firestore collection and filters out the duplicates by exploiting a simple `Set`:

```dart
Future<List> getAndFilter() async {
  final f = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final data = await f.collection('myCollection').get();
  final unfilteredData = [for (final d in data.docs) d.data()];

  final seenValues = Set();
  final desiredData = unfilteredData.where((currentDoc) {
    if (seenValues.contains(currentDoc)) return false;

    seenValues.add(currentDoc);
    return true;
  });
  
  return desiredData.toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a filter on the collection:

```
  .collection('tasks')
  .where('date', isEqualTo: selectedDate)
  .snapshots()
```

Comment: what is this selectedDate please?.. im kind of new to flutter so i will need more information

Comment: Your String variable. For example if you're using a TextField you can get the value:                                                                                                            String selectedDate = fieldController.text;                                                 (fieldController is the TextEditingController associated to your Textfield). Then just use the variable in the query..

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't solve the issue.. please read my previous comment to @venir for more clarity as to what i want to achieve.. thanks a lot